# preg_split with regex giving incorrect output

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm using preg_split to an string, but I'm not getting desired output. For example

```
$string = 'Tachycardia limit_from:1900-01-01 limit_to:2027-08-29 numresults:10 sort:publication-date direction:descending facet-on-toc-section-id:Case Reports';
$vals = preg_split("/(\w*\d?):/", $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

is generating output

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Tachycardia 
    [1] => limit_from
    [2] => 1900-01-01 
    [3] => limit_to
    [4] => 2027-08-29 
    [5] => numresults
    [6] => 10 
    [7] => sort
    [8] => publication-date 
    [9] => direction
    [10] => descending facet-on-toc-section-
    [11] => id
    [12] => Case Reports
)
```

Which is wrong, desire output it

```
Array
(
    [0] => Tachycardia 
    [1] => limit_from
    [2] => 1900-01-01 
    [3] => limit_to
    [4] => 2027-08-29 
    [5] => numresults
    [6] => 10 
    [7] => sort
    [8] => publication-date 
    [9] => direction
    [10] => descending
    [11] => facet-on-toc-section-id
    [12] => Case Reports
)
```

There something wrong with regex, but I'm not able to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use

```
$vals = preg_split("/(\S+):/", $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Output is exactly like you want

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex instead to include '-' or other characters in your splitting pattern:  http://regexr.com?32qgs

```
((?:[\w\-])*\d?):
```

Comment: @Baba Corrected that. Please check the link  again.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `\w` class does not include the character `-`, so i would expand the \w with that too:

```
/((?:\w|-)*\d?):/
```